# Why does my login page work on one branch and not the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on my blogapp while following guidance from Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial.

When I am on one branch (non-master), the login page populates fine when I request the page. However, when I am on another branch (also non-master), I get the following error:

Have I merged branches incorrectly?

users_controller.rb

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
    # Before filters

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end

routes.rb 
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/new'

  get 'blog_pages/home'

  get 'about' => 'blog_pages#about'

  get 'goodstuff' => 'blog_pages#goodstuff'

  get 'serenity' => 'blog_pages#serenity'

  get 'contact' => 'blog_pages#contact'

  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  resources :users

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
root 'application#Blog'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Comment: I think you forgot the error message.

Comment: just added routes and users controller file. The error simply displays: "we're sorry but something went wrong" when visiting /login on the second non-master branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no /login route in your routes so it looks like you failed to merge your branches.

Comment: it looks like that was the issue. Thank you @dj2